# SQL Server full text search using contains. Match text sequence with one char

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, full-text-search

I have full text indexed column name **searchMeta**

it can contain strings like

- "Module A"
- "Module B"
- "Lorem Ipsum,Module A,some more stuff here"
- "Module R6,some more stuff here"

  ```
  SELECT searchMeta from Metadata m where contains(m.SearchMeta, '"Module R6"')
  ```

will work and return the last row.

but doing

```
SELECT searchMeta from Metadata m where contains(m.SearchMeta, '"Module A"')
```

will return **all rows** instead of just the ones with **Module A**

I think it's because **contains** procedure only matches strings with at least two characters. Can I do something about that?

Comment: if it's more important to have a precise algorithm rather than a fast one then where m.SearchMeta LIKE '%"Module A"%' might do the trick, you might need escape characters to be able to use the quotes though

Comment: also you could try contains(m.SearchMeta,"Module A") to find the exact string Module A, actually I think this might just find anything with the word Module and the separate letter A in it

Comment: Not an option, I have millons of records. Using "LIKE" will take considerably longer.

Comment: Apparently Full Text Indexing comes with a list of stop words. These include all one character words and common words that do not aid in a search such as on, in, an, the, ... etc. In my case "A"

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I have created a new stop list from the standard System Stop List, and removed the "A", "B", "C", "R" which were useful in my particular scenario. The I've updated the full text index to use that custom stop list